# Testing RDP connections

Tags: remote-desktop, script

Given hostname (+ portnumber) + username + password, how do I get a yes/no answer to the question: Can I connect to host with username+password? from the commandline or a script? Is this possible?

something like:

`testRdp.(sh/exe/ps1) hostname.tld:3389 johndoe NSAbackD00R` that returns "yes"/"no" if connection+authentication is possible

I have several sites I need to log into (not regularly), and would like to get a warning, say once a day, if one of the sites have locked me out/changed password/changed firewall rules.

Comment: ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ?